# Extra argument 'isOn' in call issue with a Toggle in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, toggle

This is my code. And I always the the error: Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Bool' that does not accept a closure and Extra argument 'isOn' in call.

```
@State var isOnToggle = false
var body: some View {    
    HStack {
        Toggle(isOn: self.$isOnToggle) {
            Text("Send Notification")
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 200)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check through your code if you don't redeclare somewhere `Toggle` as your component view. It is very common mistake leading to such kind of errors.

**Caution:** as a rule of thumb - don't name your custom views similarly to standard SwiftUI views, give them instead unique names.